# Why is the AQS printed differently

Tags: java, debugging, java-8, java.util.concurrent

When I was researching AQS, I found a problem. I made a copy of the aQS and ReentrantLock source code, added printing, and then wrote a test program that, when running properly, would only print once after the thread was woken up. But when I add a breakpoint to the parkAndCheckInterrupt method, I print it twice. Why

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyReentrantLock lock = new MyReentrantLock();
        Thread thread0 = new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lock.unlock();
        });
        thread0.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            lock.unlock();
        });
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            lock.unlock();
        });
        thread2.start();

        Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            lock.unlock();
        });
        thread3.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        thread2.interrupt();
    }

    final boolean acquireQueued(final MyAbstractQueuedSynchronizer.Node node, int arg) {
        boolean failed = true;
        try {
            boolean interrupted = false;
            for (;;) {
                final MyAbstractQueuedSynchronizer.Node p = node.predecessor();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-> Spin get lock---------");**//Printed content**
                if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                    setHead(node);
                    p.next = null; // help GC
                    failed = false;
                    return interrupted;
                }
                if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                        parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                    interrupted = true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (failed)
                cancelAcquire(node);
        }
    }

    private final boolean parkAndCheckInterrupt() {
        LockSupport.park(this);
        return Thread.interrupted();**//Add a breakpoint**
    }
```

The following is the result of a normal run and a breakpoint

```
normal
Thread-1-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-1-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-3-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-3-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------

breakpoint
Thread-1-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-1-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-3-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-3-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------
Thread-2-> Spin get lock---------
```

Comment: Where is your ```MyReentrantLock``` and ```MyAbstractQueuedSynchronizer```

Comment: I made a complete copy of the AQS and ReentrantLock source code. The goal is to be able to add some printing to the code for easy debugging. Otherwise, exactly like the source code.

Comment: Hello, I am also Chinese, can I add your wechat chat?

Comment: I've reproduced what you said.  I'll take some time to look at it and answer you later.

Comment: Ok, thank you. At first, I suspected that Park and Unpark had something to do with Debug, So, I looked at the JVM source code for Park and Unpark, but didn't find anything valuable. But I think it has something to do with the debug mechanism of IDEA.

Comment: I asked a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999199/locksupport-park-miss-an-interrupt-when-debugging-in-intellij-idea.

Comment: Okay, I see that. Thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.